# Android Layout Positioing

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

This is a little bit complicated to explain, so apologies.

The basic requirement is annotator app on Android, which allows the user to draw over the desktop, take a snapshot and one or two other things.

When the app starts it shows a single icon. This can be moved about the desktop.

When this icon is single clicked (touch) 6 icons spread evenly centred around the central icon appear.

So far so good. Now we move the central icon, and re-calculate the positions of the 6 outer icons centred around the new position of the central icon.

What we find is the outer icons are off centre relative to the central icon. The displacement looks to be roughly equal (bot X and Y) by the position of the touch within the central icon.

I will attempt to draw what happens.

First when the touch point on the drag/move is in the centre, everything lines up perfectly:

[image]

When the touch point is to the right, the displacement is leftwards as below:

[image]

When the touch is at the bottom the displacement is upwards:

[image]

The position of the "x" relative to the icon is it seems from

```
int shiftX = event.getX();
int shiftY = event.getY();
```

The position of the moved icon is from :

```
view.getLocationInWindow(locWXY);
int X = locWXY[0];
int Y = locWXY[1];
```

So, the positions of the satellite icons are calculated as:

```
final double angle = 30.000;
final double rad = angle * Math.PI / 180.000;
final int radius = 100;
final int penX = (int) (X + radius * cos(rad) + shiftX);
final int penY = (int) (Y - radius * sin(rad) + shiftY);
final int clearX = X ;
final int clearY = (int) (Y - radius   + shiftY);
final int closeX = (int) (X - radius * cos(rad) + shiftX);
final int closeY = (int) (Y - radius * sin(rad)   + shiftY);
final int iFlipX = (int) (X - radius * cos(rad) + shiftX);
final int iFlipY = (int) (Y + radius * sin(rad)   + shiftY);
final int sshotX = X  + shiftX;
final int sshotY = (int) (Y + radius   + shiftY);
final int iFolderX = (int) (X + radius * cos(rad) + shiftX);
final int iFolderY = (int) (Y + radius * sin(rad)   + shiftY);

penLP= new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
penLP.leftMargin = penX;
penLP.topMargin = penY;
imbBlackPen.setLayoutParams(penLP);

clearLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
clearLP .leftMargin = clearX;
clearLP .topMargin = clearY;
imbClearScreen.setLayoutParams(clearLP );

folderLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
folderLP .leftMargin = iFolderX ;
folderLP .topMargin = iFolderY;
imbFolder.setLayoutParams(folderLP );

sshotLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
sshotLP .leftMargin = sshotX ;
sshotLP .topMargin = sshotY;
imbScreenCapture.setLayoutParams(sshotLP );

iFlipLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
iFlipLP .leftMargin = iFlipX ;
iFlipLP .topMargin = iFlipY;
imbIflipChart.setLayoutParams(iFlipLP );

closeLP = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(70, 70);
closeLP .leftMargin = closeX ;
closeLP .topMargin = closeY;
imbClose.setLayoutParams(closeLP );
```

I have tried setting shiftX and shiftY to zero, calculating X and X + shiftX/2. All to no avail`.` The strange thing is that on a small 10 inch tablet with resolution 1920 x 1200 it looks almost perfect, but on a large 65 inch touch screen the displacement is extremely pronounced.

We must be missing something, but I cannot figure out what.

Comment: Fixed. The icon position calculation code above needed to be executed on ACTION_UP as well as ACTION_DOWN. Refacttored this as a metthod and called it on both these events.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above ...

Fixed. The icon position calculation code above needed to be executed on ACTION_UP as well as ACTION_DOWN. Refactored this as a method and called it on both these events.